# Gilab CI runner and error "Checking out 1b64453a as detached HEAD (ref is develop)"

Tags: build, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use Gitlab CI to build the application and at some point an error appeared when the Gitlab CI application started to issue the error "Checking out ... as detached HEAD (ref is develop)".
At the same time, Gitlab CI does nothing in this job. Just writes this message and executes further, other jobs.

What could be the reason and how to solve it?

1. I tried to re-register gitlab ci, but the error did not go away.
2. I tried to make new comets, but the error remained